# VB.NET Manipulate array to parse

Tags: vb.net

How to get this:

```
a 1
b 1
c 1
e 2
f 2
c 2
b 3
c 3
f 3
a 4
b 4
c 4
```

into this:

```
a   1,4
b   1,3,4
c   1,2,3,4
e   2
f   2,3
```

I am right now storing the data in a 2-diemnsional array.
However I still need to be able to get the individual numbers after parsing them.
For example in *a* I need to be able to go get some more data from entries 1 and 4, do some math, and put that into another column like this:

```
a   1,4       36
b   1,3,4     98
c   1,2,3,4   23
e   2         45
f   2,3       12
```

Edit:
I should note that in the 2 columns I am using numbers of variable length. Sorry for the confusion of the letters as I wanted to show clearly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

(In C# as I'm not fond of VB's syntax for generics, but it should still be mutually intelligible):

Conceptually you're mapping each character with a growing list of integers, your question doesn't state if preserving the order is important, but I assume it is (though if not, just use a `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>`).

I assume your list of input data is already structured as a tuple (`Pair<Char,Int32>`).

```
Dictionary< Char, List<Int32> > map = new Dictionary< Char, List<Int32> >();
foreach(Pair<Char,Int32> entry in input) {
    Char c = entry.First;
    if( !map.ContainsKey( c ) ) {
        map.Add( c, new List<Int32>() );
    }
    map[ c ].Add( entry.Second );
}
```

Comment: I should be able to use this with Pair<Int32,Int32> correct? (See edit above)

Comment: Also after doing this any ideas about adding another column of data(the math bot from above)?